# A Question on CSS Nesting without Violating DRY Philosophy

Tags: html, css, dry, nested

Out of curiosity I'm wondering if I can do something about this because I'm lazy. So I have this:

```
<tr class="headerRow">
     <td><a href='?sortby=title'>Title</a></td>
     <td><a href='?sortby=date'>Date</a></td>
     <td><a href='?sortby=outlet'>Media Outlet</a></td>
     <td><a href='?sortby=author'>Author</a></td>
     <td><a href='?sortby=region'>Location</a></td>
     <td>Tags</td>
</tr>
```

I don't want to have the links within this row to be underlined.  However, I'd rather not place class="blah" for each link in the row, because that would be a violation of DRY.  Is there a way to place a single tag to enforce a certain style on these links, *without* having to place code on each individual link or causing all links on the page to be un-underlined?  Some nesting technique perhaps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, just use [CSS selectors](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/selectorref):

```
.headerRow td a { text-decoration: none; }
.headerRow td a:hover { text-decoration: underline; }
```

Comment: Thanks Wex!  I was pretty sure that CSS would have an easy solution to this, I just wasn't savvy enough to know it yet.

Comment: Even better perhaps, change the table cells to proper table headers (`<th scope="col">...</th>`) and not only can you leave out the extra class in the `<tr>` and just use `th a {...` in the style sheet, but you add semantic structure to the table.